# Is there a summary showing how many times users have earned a badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, activity-summary

I know that I can look at the badge info to see who has recently earned a badge. I also know that I can go to an *individual's* profile and see a summary of how many times he or she has earned a specific badge.

But for badges that can be earned more than once, is there a summary page that orders users from most to least number of times the badge has been earned. So lets say something like:

```
Nice Answer

SoAndSoUser1     x231
SoAndSoUser2     x228
SoAndSoUser3     x227
...
SoAndSoUser42468 x1
```

**If such a page exists, can someone point me to it?**

**If not, perhaps it is something worth adding.** It would reflect a little different perspective than pure reputation (especially for badges that are not even based in any way on reputation).

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com will solve all of your needs.

Comment: That is interesting to learn about (I didn't know it existed). However, I am in no way a database person. My expertise is in web design (CSS, LESS, some javascript). So I do not know how to even begin building a query to get the data mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEXDEX)](http://data.stackexchange.com) was made for this purpose, so I have made you a query which should emulate what you want. Feel free to play around with it: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/115712/

```sql
select distinct top 25 b.UserId as [User Link], b.Name, COUNT(b.Id)
from Badges b
where b.Name = '##BadgeName##'
group by b.UserId, b.Name
order by COUNT(b.Id) DESC
```

Results:

```
User Link              Name             
---------------------- ----------- ---- 
Jon Skeet              Nice Answer 4084 
Marc Gravell           Nice Answer 1207 
Eric Lippert           Nice Answer 1179 
Darin Dimitrov         Nice Answer 903  
BalusC                 Nice Answer 787  
JaredPar               Nice Answer 735  
Alex Martelli          Nice Answer 697  
Mark Byers             Nice Answer 645  
SLaks                  Nice Answer 636  
paxdiablo              Nice Answer 608  
Johannes Schaub - litb Nice Answer 592  
Greg Hewgill           Nice Answer 589  
VonC                   Nice Answer 588  
cletus                 Nice Answer 566  
CMS                    Nice Answer 549  
James McNellis         Nice Answer 531  
Reed Copsey            Nice Answer 517  
Mehrdad Afshari        Nice Answer 517  
Konrad Rudolph         Nice Answer 489  
Nick Craver            Nice Answer 468  
Pascal Thivent         Nice Answer 467  
KennyTM                Nice Answer 454  
tvanfosson             Nice Answer 411  
CommonsWare            Nice Answer 386  
S.Lott                 Nice Answer 383
```

Comment: Yes, that gives me what I was looking for. Thank you very much! Also, thank you for letting me know the site exists (even if I do need to study up on database querying to use it).

Comment: Data Exchange is only refreshed occasionally, no?

Comment: @AlEverett I believe weekly or bi-weekly.